# Bing Maps v7 writing words on map

Tags: bing-maps

I'm working on a product that will show information about individual counties in Wisconsin. Is it possible to programmatically write the county's name on the map? The only option I've seen to do this is by creating a tile layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a blog post on how to achieve this here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/label-pushpins-in-bing-maps-v7/

Here is the code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         var map = null;         

         function GetMap()
         {
            // Initialize the map
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"),
                  {
                    credentials:"YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY"
                  }); 

            var labelPin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0,0),{
                text : 'Custom Label',    //The text for the label
                typeName : 'labelPin',     //Assign a CSS class to the pin
                anchor : new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0,0),  //Reset the anchor point of the pin to make aligning the text easier.
                textOffset : new Microsoft.Maps.Point(-45,0) //Adjust textOffset point for better label positioning
                //Adjust the x value as you see fit for better centering of text
            });

            map.entities.push(labelPin);
         } 
      </script>
      <style>
      /* Allow div of pushpin to display overflowing content */
      .labelPin{
        overflow:visible !important;
      }

      /* Hide the default pushpin, Alternatively point the icon property of the pushpin to a transparent image */
      .labelPin img{
        display:none;
      }

      /*Use this to style the text*/
      .labelPin div{
        white-space:nowrap;
        color:blue !important;
      }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetMap();">
    <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:800px; height:600px;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Pushpin with a custom image, and set the custom image to a transparent image, so all you see is the Pushpin text.  To make it real easy, you can even specify a base64 encoded transparent image inline directly, as shown below:

```
var pushpinOptions = {
    icon: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==",/* Transparent 1px x 1px gif with a 1bit palette, created with gimp and encoded with base64 tool in linux.*/
    text: 'Your county name goes here',
    draggable: false,
    visible: true,
};
var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6, - 122.33), pushpinOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are using for the back end but the way I would accomplish this is by doing the following:

ajax call back to the server, get an object that returns the following or something similar
{CountyName = 'Iron', latitude = '23', longitude = -100}

on the call back iterate though that and populate custom info boxes.